# Why can't I exclude a term ID from either get_terms or WP_Term_query?

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post tipe ("artigo"), and this CPT has a registered taxonomy ("artigo_eixo"), with 3 registered terms in it.

**I want to show, in that page, a sidebar listing all terms,** ***except the current term,*** in the page that lists all posts with that term (http://localhost/mytaxonomy/current_term/)

However, I can't exclude the current term from the query.

I'm trying to get a list of taxonomy terms, but exclude a certain term from this list. I'm trying to follow the codex examples, but I'm having no success, using either `get_terms()` or `WP_Term_query()`.

There are 3 terms and the IDs are 13,14,15. There are no posts or CPT items with those IDs.

I just tested `get_queried_object_id()` and it seems to be returning the proper term IDs of the term being shown -- that is, if I am viewing the URL of the term with ID 13, the function returns 13, and so on.

It also doesn't work using hardcoded values, be it a string, an integer, or an array of any of those types. Neither won't work:

```
'exclude' => 14
'exclude' => '14'
'exclude' => array(14)
'exclude' => array('14')
```

There are no errors displayed by PHP or the WP debug log.

## get_terms

```
if (is_tax( 'artigo_eixo' )) {

    $current_eixo = get_queried_object_id();

    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'artigo_eixo',
        'exclude' => $current_eixo
    );

    $eixos = get_terms( $args );
```

## WP_Term_query

```
if (is_tax( 'artigo_eixo' )) {

    $current_eixo = get_queried_object_id();

    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => array('artigo_eixo'),
        'exclude' => $current_eixo
    );

    $eixos = new WP_Term_Query( $args );
    $eixos = $eixos->terms;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a function hooking the filter `list_terms_exclusions`, and the return was inside a logically faulty conditional. I fixed it and now the term query exclusion works as intended.